# Teamcity deployment to another server via ssh

Tags: plugins, deployment, ssh, teamcity, war

I'm trying to use teamcity **deployer plugin** to send my build result (war file) via ssh to another computer in network.
my problem is how to config deployer to find my builded war file.
I used %teamcity.build.workingDir%**/*.war in Artifacts path setting but it can not find any file in there.

The log show that it try to find my file in here /home/teamcity/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/c4bca27d2b00a6fe**/*.war.

the path is correct but It's not working...

the teamcity document for Accessing Build Artifacts is not clear, and  does not show what should i use in setting dialog.

Update:

I tried to use **/mywar-1.0.war and **/build/libs/mywar-1.0.war, both works but now the problem is, it deploy the file with it's subdirectories like this dest/build/libs/mywar-1.0.war

but i need dest/mywar-1.0.war,
so still don't know how to configure it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teamcity deployer plugin, uses pattern as a Artifacts path to find files for deploy, in most cases as @Vlad said using `**/*.fileType` or `**/filename.type` is enough,

for example : `**/*.war` or `**/myprojectfile.war`

but sometimes your output files are in subdirectory tree, so using pattern case the deployer to create those subdirectories on destination.
in this case, I just need the war file without its subdirectory so the right way is using complete path to that file.

for example : 
my war file is in `build/libs/` folder after build process

so using `build/libs/mywar.war` as a Artifacts path, will deploy the war to destination without its subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Artifacts resolved under checkout directory [as documentation says](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-PathsPatterns), so just `**/*.war` is enough.

Comment: With that command it deploy all war file in build project that I don't want, I just need one of them.

Comment: Your original question contained `**/*.war`, so my answer too. Regarding directory change, try `**/myname-1.0.war => dest/`

Comment: I tried this  `**/mywar-1.0.war => dest/` and got this `dest/build/libs/mywar-1.0.war` !? any other idea?

Comment: `/build/libs/mywar-1.0.war => dest/` ? :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the answer, so I'll post it here to help other people who may have same problem.